# org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Cannot extract a capabilities from the request

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android, remotewebdriver, appium-desktop

When I use a remotewebdriver to instantiate, I perfectly get the object returned.

But instead of remotewebdriver if I use AndroidDriver, then I am getting the below error. Kindly help.

```
2018-09-27 12:17:09.712:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp817406040-14: /wd/hub/session java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Cannot extract a capabilities from the request: {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "appPackage": "com.xxxxxxx.ymca",
    "clearSystemFiles": "true",
    "noReset": "true",
    "noSign": true,
    "deviceName": "Altitude",
    "fullReset": "false",
    "version": "",
    "platform": "ANDROID",
    "appWaitDuration": 60,
    "appActivity": "com.ytlcomms.ymca.activities.LoginActivity",
    "newCommandTimeout": 60,
    "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
    "autoGrantPermissions": true,
    "browserName": "android",
    "platformName": "Android"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "alwaysMatch": {
      "appium:appActivity": "com.ytlcomms.ymca.activities.LoginActivity",
      "appium:appPackage": "com.xxxxxxxx.ymca",
      "appium:appWaitDuration": 60,
      "appium:autoGrantPermissions": true,
      "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
      "browserName": "android",
      "appium:clearSystemFiles": "true",
      "appium:deviceName": "Altitude",
      "appium:fullReset": "false",
      "appium:newCommandTimeout": 60,
      "appium:noReset": "true",
      "appium:noSign": true,
      "platform": "ANDROID",
      "platformName": "android",
      "version": ""
    },
    "firstMatch": [
      {
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what the stack trace tells:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities: [platform, version]
```

I am using the below code instantiate.

```
RemoteWebDriver getDriver(String appName, String appPackage, String appActivity) {
    DesiredCapabilities androidDcap = DesiredCapabilities.android();
    if (appName.equalsIgnoreCase("YMCA"))
        androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Altitude");
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.CLEAR_SYSTEM_FILES, true);
    androidDcap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
    androidDcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
    androidDcap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.NO_SIGN, true);
    androidDcap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, true);
    androidDcap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_WAIT_DURATION, 60);
    androidDcap.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 60);
    androidDcap.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);
    androidDcap.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);
    try {
        if (System.getProperty("location").equalsIgnoreCase("local")) {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4651/wd/hub"), androidDcap);
        } else {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(PropertyHelper.getProperties("REMOTE_HUB_URL")), androidDcap);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Driver instantiating failed", e);
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

Appium Java client version: 6.1.0
Selenium standalone version: 3.14.0

Comment: Might it be as simple as your "version" capability parameter as no value? ("")

Comment: @BillHileman I solved this. I was instantiating the desired capabilities as below:

`desiredCapabilities dcap = desiredCapabilities.iPhone()`

I changed it to:

`desiredCapabilities dcap = new desiredCapabilities()`

The first approach was adding those 2 params automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved by downgrading selenium-standalone-server-3.13.0

The problem here is you are supposed to use the selenium-standalone-server version given in java-client. In my case, I'm using java-client-6.1.0. for that, we need to use selenium-standalone-server-3.13.0

[Please see here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/655#issuecomment-404477788).

you can get the older version of jar files [here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my setup of web execution over chrome browser and finally find out the solution.

I was passing my capability as below (was throwing same error as mentioned here)

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
```

Changed to below and it worked

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
```